# 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' in Eclipse IDE

Tags: python, eclipse, numpy, python-camelot

I am running Eclipse IDE 4.20.0 with a PyDev Interpreter on Windows10. I am trying try to get [Camelot][1] to run within my script but continue to get the error-

"***Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'***"

For each, I have used pip install to install camelot, tabula-py, numpy, pandas, etc. and all of them seemed to install appropriately. My Eclipse Project Properties PYTHONPATH is pointed to the install location and I haven't had issues with other libraries I have installed previously.

The Python version is: Python3.7
The NumPy version is: "1.21.5"

I also tried reverting numpy to an older version (1.15.1) but had no success there based on other posts that I have seen here on stackoverflow. Additionally, I have read the numpy support site that is listed in the error below but can't find anything that would be of note in my system as an issue...

Ultimately, I am attempting to read tables from a PDF in python but it seems that the libraries available (camelot, tabula, etc.) all give me the same issue with numpy. Any suggestions here would be greatly appreciated.

The full error that I am getting is -

---

ImportError:
IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
Importing the numpy C-extensions failed.
This error can happen for many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was installed.
We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
Please note and check the following:

- The Python version is: Python3.7 from "C:\Users~~~\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
- The NumPy version is: "1.21.5"
  and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
  Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.
  Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

---